# Trouble connecting to database--java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, database, derby

I am trying to do something with databases and failing miserably..please help!

This is my code, up until the point of the SQLNonTransientConnectionException:

```
public class UFTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{ 

   Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
   ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
   ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
   ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "User");
   ht.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pw");
System.out.println("cx/ht succesful");       
   Context cx = null;
   Connection con = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   String source = "jdbc/LF_JHU_DERBY";
   File file = new File("Student_List.txt"); 

   try{
System.out.println("try entered");           
       cx = new InitialContext(ht);
System.out.println("cx created"); 
       Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:7001/LF_JHU_Derby;create=true","User", "pw");
```

At this point I get this:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at randomtests.UFTest.main(UFTest.java:38)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.
at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.fill(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.ensureALayerDataInBuffer(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.readDssHeader(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.startSameIdChainParse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readExchangeServerAttributes(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readServerAttributesAndKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowServerAttributesAndKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowUSRIDPWDconnect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

Now, I am running the Weblogic server at which the DB should have been created on port 7001. I notice that if I pick a random port number, the errors I get tell me that it was "refused." Here that is not the case--it is accepted…just there is no response.

Also, at the line:

```
cx = new InitialContext(ht);
```

I get the following:

```
Problem creating dummy orb: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 203  completed: No
```

which, in spite of googling, do not understand (and certainly don't know how to fix). I don't know if the issues are connected or not…Please help!

This is from the commandline (about the creation of the DB):

```
ij> CONNECT 'jdbc:derby:LF_JHU_Derby;create=true';
CREATE TABLE STUDENT ( FIRST_NAME varchar(40), LAST_NAME varchar(40) , SSN char(11) ,          EMAIL varchar(40), ADDRESS varchar(40), USERID varchar(8) , PASSWORD varchar(8) );
quit;ij> 0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
```

And then later, tested with:

```
ij> CONNECT 'jdbc:derby:LF_JHU_Derby;create=true';
WARNING 01J01: Database 'LF_JHU_Derby' not created, connection made to existing database       instead.
```

So, it seems to exist, then...

Comment: I have noticed that this issue continues even if I explicitly alter the URL to read, for example,  jdbc:derby://localhost:7001/LF_JHU_Derby1;
So…the network is there, but the connection to databse isn't working..presumably because it can't find it. But why?

Comment: The Derby Network Server may be placing messages into its derby.log file. Have you looked there?

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
@Transient
```

annotation at top of the method you used this, try deleting that annotation and then keep going...